# curllib POST body data (How to?)

Tags: c++, post, curl

Please show me how to make post of big text data with curllib? I want to make it not using parameters like &data="some big text", but using POST body;

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple case is just CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html

If you want to send lots of data, perhaps use a CURLOPT_READFUNCTION callback: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html

... or if you're talking about doing a multipart formpost, you want CURLOPT_HTTPPOST: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html